# Где найти изображения в высоком качестве для сайтов?

Tags: изображения

Ищу изображения в очень хорошем и высоком качестве для использования в качестве фонового изображения для сайта. Где можно найти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на имадж-стоках купить http://www.istockphoto.com/, http://www.gettyimages.com/, http://www.shutterstock.com/ru/

Answer (score 1):

в гугле,
в фото банках